# Prevent HTML drop on div where other <img> has already been dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
    
    var result = [];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var imgId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var boxId = ev.target.id;
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(imgId));
        result.push(imgId, boxId);
        document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHTML = result;
    }
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHTML = result;
    }
```

```css
.dragBox {
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">

       <div class="col-sm-3">
       <img id="115" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968" class="dragme" height="150" width="100%" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
       </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
       <img id="116" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/gr_en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg" class="dragme" height="150" width="100%" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
       </div>
        <p id="outputBox"></p>

        <div class="row createWhitespaceBottom" id="fotoblok">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="questionId" class="form-control" id="questionId" value="<?php echo $question[0]; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="questionType" class="form-control" id="questionType" value="<?php echo $question[1]; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dragBox" id="box1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dragBox" id="box2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dragBox" id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dragBox" id="box4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<span class="input-group-btn createWhitespaceTop"><button onclick="myFunction()"  id="antwoordblok2" class="btn btn-primary" value="Opslaan">Opslaan</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I have created 4 images which should be dragged to 4 four boxes. Each image belongs to one certain box and I need to check if the user has dragged it to the correct box when clicking on the submit button.

The problem: Users can drag all images to the same box, basically deleting the images which where there before.

Preferred solution: When an image is already in the box, you can not drag another to it. You can, however, drag the image to another box to correct your answer.

note: For now the javascript return through innerHTML the id of the image and the box. I created this to check its working. In the end this will be send using _POST to be handled by PHP.

I have taken a look at some solutions suggested already at stackoverflow but was not able to get those working. This is probarly due to the fact I dont know javascript/jQuery so well.

Comment: create a flag and set it to true when you drop an image and make a condition that checks if flag is true or not

Comment: you can ask if that div to drop got a previous img inside.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the dropped div has an img element inside like this:

```
if($("#"+ev.target.id).find("img").length==0 && ev.target.tagName!="IMG")
```

Your drop function will look like this:

```
 function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var imgId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var boxId = ev.target.id;
        if($("#"+ev.target.id).find("img").length==0 && ev.target.tagName!="IMG"){
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(imgId));
          result.push(imgId, boxId);
          document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHTML = result;
        }
    }
```

Try to avoid using flags, because they are not nice and most of the times they are globals and global variables are not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. However it seems to work only for the second img you try to drag onto another img.

Test:
- drag an image to a square
- drag another img to the same square, it gets dropped over the first one,
- JS innerHTML now returns 115,box2,115,116
- Only when you try to drop a third, it will not work

when dragging from box to box, it will work all the time

Comment: Why not checking you result Array if it has this boxId already?

Comment: Because when you dragOver the image, the older image is gone. They need to put all four images in a box, but never more than one image in one box.

When they try to put a second image in an box, it should bounce back to its starting position.

Comment: Now it looks like this:
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var imgId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var boxId = ev.target.id;
        var boxClass = ev.target.className;
        if (boxClass == 'dragBox') {
            if ($("#" + ev.target.id).find("img").length == 0) {
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(imgId));
                result.push(imgId, boxId);
            }
        } else {
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(imgId));
        }
    }

but, still i can drop images over each other.

Comment: Try this one: if($("#"+ev.target.id).find("img").length==0 && ev.target.tagName!="IMG")